# How to return current date in format "YYYY-mm-dd" as a Date datatype?

Tags: android

I know there are many ways to solve this but I am looking for a simple one line solution.
Typically it would be

```
 new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date())
```

However this returns a string and I need an object of the Date type.

Using the GregorianCalendar class is okay too since it can return a Date type.

thanks

Comment: I don't get you... Treat the date as date. And display it as string.

Comment: `Date` objects don't have an inherent format; they're only formatted when converting to `Strings`

Comment: What @TheoKanning said is correct.  You're confused on this issue-  either you want a string, or you want a Date.  Date objects don't have or need a format until you print them.  WHen you do that then you format it.

Answer (score 3):

Try it out in this way:

```
     String strDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime())
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();        
     SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat();
     sdf1.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
     Date date = sdf1.parse(strDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Date dateObj =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse( new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Date d = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).parse("2011-12-13");
```

or

```
Date now = new Date();
```